# OpenCV findContour() returning too many contours (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I am having a problem with CV.drawContours. I am inputting this picture here.

[image]

However the output is slightly larger and creates contours of some space that wasn't part of the picture. Here is what the output looks like
[image]

As you can see, there is an increased area along the left and bottom sides as well as contour lines being traced (in green). I am following this tutorial [on OpenCV Contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc), but looking at both the tutorial and some documentation didn't make it very clear to me what kind of problem this is. Here is my code that I have.

Given that we are seeing green lines outside of the original picture, I'd guess that something is going on with `cv.findContours` and it is picking up additional possible external contour lines and is thinking the black outline in the original picture are internal contour lines (although that would not explain why it is only happening to half of the sides).

```
import cv2 as cv

# Find contours
im = cv.imread("binary_graph_8.png")
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw countours
cv.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)

#Issue - function shows more than 100% of entire image...2/17/2019
cv.imshow("window title", im)
cv.waitKey()
```

Comment: Use `cv::RETR_EXTERNAL` instead `cv.RETR_TREE`

Comment: What was your reasoning for thinking that would help? Btw it didn't change anything

Comment: Check my answer, you will see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently struggled with the same issue and the only solution I found was to filter gained contours using hierarchy. Of course, it's a bad-style solution, but it worked for me.

In your case, you should predict only two possible troubles.

1. Your have such areas in the result hierarchy. You can surely say that there is no anything inside them so just ignore first-level contours without nested children
2. The whole image you promote may be nested into one more contour. It's not a problem then to extract it using hierarchy.

All in all, I would rather write a couple of lines of code to check this options then plunge deep into opencv's guts.

I guess, the best tutorial about contours' hierarchy is [there](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Comment: Avoid doing things by yourself if they're already available via API, the `RETR_EXTERNAL` do what OP wants, so no need for extra checking to such a lot of contours which returns by `RETR_TREE` that causes an overhead problem, especially while using in real-time.

Comment: @Smooth ah okay, that makes sense. I originally wanted to start at contours hierarchy, then I realized it is probably better to start at the beginning of the contours tutorial :) I plan on working through the entire series. This gives me a better understanding of what result hierarchy will be used for in the future

Answer (score 6):

You can use `RETR_EXTERNAL` instead `RETR_TREE` to return only external contours as shown below:

**Using RETR_EXTERNAL:**

[image]

**Using RETR_TREE:**

[image]

Comment: I don't think OP was looking for this in an answer.

Comment: not what I was looking for unless there is a way to use RETR_EXTERNAL to additionally filter out the most bottom-left 90 degree contour lines with it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uwqvj6C - I squiggled out the areas that should not be in the output picture

Comment: @EvanKim Now you have two contours and you can simply filter the one you don't want via width and height which returns by `boundingRect()` of the OpenCV.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil how can I know which width and height to input to use as a filter for boundingRect()? The width and height will change when I use different sized pictures

Comment: @EvanKim You can compare width the current image width and height. Like the image, you provided the contour which you want to filter is almost the same width and height as the image itself, you can easily detect and filter out. Or you can also use the noneZero/totalArea of the contour which will you the percentage of its content, the higher the better. It depends on your data which technic is the best to choose, as the current image the first technic is OK.